# When minimizing my application window it is going to clumsy

Tags: kendo-ui

I am doing one project using  kendo controls.Its almost completed but one issue is raised,that is when minimizing window all application is  going to clumsy.That is all controls positions are slightly moved so its viewed as clumsy.how to solve this issue.please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try this  one

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
 $("#chart svg").width(Number($('.k-content').width()));
 $("#chart svg").height(Number($('.k-content').height()));
 $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
 });
```

Comment: Its working fine but I am using stock chart in my application.I tried this code for stock chart but its not working properly.

Comment: For stock chart ou can use like this $("#chart").data("kendoStockChart").refresh();